# Is it possible to select an element based on an attribute and the value of text in between the element tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am looking for a css selector that would select the following element based on supplying the class atrribute and some_text

```
<a class="some_class">some_text</a>
```

I've tried a few things, but can't get the elemented selected. Please help.

Comment: It is possible using JavaScript/jQuery but you can't do this by CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
.some_class{
  /* apply your styles here */  
}
```

The above will take care of class attribute.

But, it isn't possible to select elements based on their inner text.

Answer (score 0):

No.  As mentioned by the other answers, you can't restrict based on the content of a tag without using Javascript.

You can utilise other attributes though:

```
<a class="some_class" data-text="some_text">Some content</a>
```

using

```
.some_class[data-text=some_text] {}
```

or

```
<input class="some_class" type="text" name="myname" />
```

using

```
.some_class[name=myname] {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This required selector is not available in case of CSS. So you need to specify a new class or need to take halp of jQuery or javascript.

**Using CSS**

`a.class-name {
    /* Your css */
}`

**Using jQuery**

`if(jQuery('a.class-name').text() == 'some_text'){
    jQuery('a.class-name').css({
        /*Your css*/
    });
}`

This would be best! Till CSS provides that privilege :)